# Is there a way to make Hunspell accept real quotes (‘’ “”) instead of ignoring them in the user dictionary?

Tags: affix, hunspell

I use real quotes instead of straight quotes in my writing in everything. Straight quotes are reserved for programs to indicate literal strings. Since using real quotation marks for indicating titles and quotes, this makes sense to keep this usage from being confuse with the programming code. I use Apache OpenOffice mostly. Even putting entries in the exception dictionaries do not work. Most other text editors stop flagging the word as misspelled when I put it in the user dictionary. I asked at the OpenOffice forums. They told me it was a problem with the AFF file Hunspell uses.

I have tried entering the word in the user dictionary. For example: Hallowe’en
Hunspell still does not accept this. It not only flags Hallowe’en, but offers it as a replacement.

I am not a developer. I just want to change Hunspell to accept real quotation marks since the developers are not doing this, or won’t. So fine, I will do it myself. Apparently this is controlled in the AFF file. What code would I need to change to get the dictionary to stop flagging real quotes, and accept them in the user dictionaries?

Comment: It’s okay. I figured it out myself. There are several files to change in OpenOffice. They are in the folder of the English dictionary file in C:\Users\<profile>\AppData\Roaming\OpenOffice\4\user\uno_packages\cache\user_packages\<coded number>\<name of dictionary>.OXT\. The files of interest are en_US.aff, en_US.dic, th_en_US_v2.idx, and th_en_US_v2.dat. (continued)

Comment: For the AFF file you change the fourth line so:
ICONV ’ ' to ICONV ' ’
and on the line SFX M   0    's     . you change ' to ’

The easiest way to find the 's is to simply use a text editor and do a search and replace from ' to ’. Then make sure that line 4 is still ICONV ' ’.

The others you simply change all straight apostrophes to real apostrophes using search and replace. Make sure en_US.dic is Hallowe’en and not Halloween. (continued)

Comment: In th_en_US_v2.idx find halloween and change it to hallowe’en.

In th_en_US_v2.dat use find to locate the lines

allhallows eve|1
(noun)|Halloween|Hallowe'en|Allhallows Eve|day (generic term)

Change the second line to
(noun)|Hallowe’en|Halloween|Allhallows Eve|day (generic term)

That is all there is to it. Make sure to take out any entries for Hallowe’en (and variations) in the Exceptions.dic and any custom dictionary.